# Anaconda prompts me to create new environment in order to update Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a fresh install of Anaconda, which came with Spyder 3.3.3. I used Anaconda Prompt to install Spyder 3.3.4. Then in Anaconda Navigator I select the gear over Spyder 3.3.3 and select Update. I get a message reading:

> spyder==3.3.4 cannot be installed on this environment. Do you want to
>   install the package on an existing environment or create a new
>   environment?

I don't want to install this on a separate environment though. What's going on?

Edit: When I use Anaconda Prompt to update (not install, sorry) Spyder this is what I get:

> WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in
>   a future release. Collecting package metadata: done Solving
>   environment: done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - spyder
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> conda-package-han~
>   pkgs/main/win-64::conda-package-handling-1.3.10-py37_0
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> conda                                       4.6.11-py37_0 -->
>   4.7.5-py37_0
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing
>   transaction: done
>
> (base) C:\Windows\system32>ET _sysp=%~dpA 'ET' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> (base) C:\Windows\system32>IF NOT EXIST "!_sysp!\Scripts\conda.exe"
>   WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained
>   to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have
>   conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove
>   conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
>   Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
>   done
>
> ## All requested packages already installed.

Comment: From your question it sounds to me like you already installed 3.3.4 using Anaconda Prompt and Anaconda Navigator just didn't update itself properly. Are you sure you're still on 3.3.3 when you open up Spyder? Edit: Try typing `conda list spyder` in your Anaconda prompt to check.

Comment: @IanKent This is what I get:

# packages in environment at C:\Users\zeoco\Anaconda3:

#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

spyder                    3.3.3                    py37_0

spyder-kernels            0.5.0                    py37_0

Comment: What happens when you type `conda update spyder`?

Comment: That's the command I used when I updated (not installed, sorry) as in the original post. I edited the post to add that comment data.

Comment: Try `conda update -c anaconda spyder` and see if it's any different

Comment: That definitely had different behavior! Took a while downloading and installing stuff. However, the version listed in Anaconda Navigator is still 3.3.3, and selecting Update there still gives the same message as before about not being able to install on the current environment. Now when I type `conda list spyder` I get nearly the same result as before, only with a different value of 0.4.2 for spyder-kernels.

Comment: This remains unresolved. Anything I can do other than keep using the old version?

Comment: It could be that the required dependencies for the newest version of spyder can't be resolved with the versions of the many, many packages that come with Anaconda so it's keeping the older version of spyder. Welcome to what they call dependency hell. You can try `conda install -c anaconda spyder=3.3.5`. It might try to downgrade some of your other packages or might fail outright, in which case, yeah you either have to just wait till the next version of Anaconda or ditch Anaconda and install only the packages you need with Miniconda instead.

Comment: Oof, good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a problem while clicking install spyder in anaconda navigator as well. Solved this issue with some steps. While making a new environment in navigator, you may see the checkbox with python version (or r version) versions. In my case python 3.10.4 was available (which I had installation error at) as latest version. Instead I selected python 3.9.12. Coming back at home page in this environment, clicking install spyder did not give any error. So try selecting a lower version (or the default version) of python in the checkbox while making a new environment. (As a side note my spyder version was latest and 5.1.5)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same error as you have mentioned. Googling didn't provide any answer.

I removed all my other environments except the base environment and then updated all the packages through command prompt using  `conda update --all`

Using just `conda update spyder` will also work I think, after removing all but the base environment.